# How to perform arithmetic operations inside concatenating string in PHP?

Tags: php, concatenation

This code:

```
$a = "100";
echo "abc" . $a - 1;
```

prints out `-1` instead of `abc99`.

Obvious workaround would be:

```
$a = "100";
$tmp = $a - 1;
echo "abc" . $tmp;
```

But is there a way to calculate `$a - 1` without creating temporary variable?

Comment: `echo "abc" .( $a - 1);` just wrap your calculation in parentheses

Comment: see http://docs.php.net/language.operators.precedence : " Parentheses may be used to force precedence, if necessary. For instance: (1 + 5) * 3 evaluates to 18."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `sprintf` for printing concatenations as you have more control and felexbility.

```
echo sprintf("abc%d" , $a - 1;");
```

This way you make sure that the calcuation is executed on it's own and you could also use the other powerfull `sprintf` features.

Comment: I strongly(!) agree:  make your code explicit and obvious.  PHP is a very ambiguous language that tries *(much too hard ...)* to "do what it thought you meant."   Strive to make your code "obvious and unambiguous, to the naked eye."  If that means using temporaries, do it.  If that means `sprintf` as shown here, do that.